# How to embed SVG within foreignObject?

Tags: xml, svg

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/foreignObject):

**Any SVG elements within a foreignObject will not be drawn, except in the situation where a properly defined SVG subdocument with a proper xmlns attribute specification is embedded recursively.**

I've tried setting the proper namespaces to all subsequent elements without any succes.

What i'm trying to accomplish is roughly this:

```html
<svg>
   <foreignObject>
      some html text
      <svg width="10" height="10"><rect fill="red" width="10" height="10" /></svg>
   </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have a single element inside the foreignObject, although that element may have children. So you can do this...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">some html text
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10"><rect fill="red" width="10" height="10" /></svg>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your result trying to  ``<img src="./path/toSVG.svg"/>``

Comment: foreignObject does not work in img elements in Chrome. It does in Firefox.